# Fourier transform of shifted rect function

Tags: fourier-transform

when computing the Fourier transform of $\mbox{rect}(\frac{x}{2})$ where it's equal to $1$ from $-1<x<1$ and zero for $|x|>1$.

When computing I ended up with $\frac{\sin(2\pi s)}{\pi s}$. I know $\mbox{sinc}(s)$ is defined as $\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s}$ however I'm not sure how much answer relates to $\mbox{sinc}$ as using the properties of the shifted rect it should be $2\mbox{sinc}(2x)$. e.g. is $\frac{\sin(2\pi s)}{\pi s}= 2\mbox{sinc}(2s)$?
thanks!

Comment: Yes, as you said $\mbox{sinc}(s)=\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s}$, so setting $2x=s$, you get $\mbox{sinc}(2x)=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi x}\rightarrow 2\mbox{sinc}(2x)=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x}$

Comment: Thanks so much, alot more obvious doing it simply like that. Thanks again!